Unstack Columns into New Columns with Names from Stacked Values
I have a dataframe with repeating id numbers, repeating categories, and numeric values that may or not repeat. I need a final dataframe with each row being one id number with fields showing the values per category.
Original dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDNum': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'Category': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
                   'value1': [1.5, 2.2, 3.6, 5.1, 6.0, 1.0], 'value2': [2.0, 3.6, 4.5, 8.2, 6.1, 1.2]})

df

    IDNum   Category    value1  value2
0   1       a           1.5     2.0
1   1       b           2.2     3.6
2   2       a           3.6     4.5
3   3       c           5.1     8.2
4   3       b           6.0     6.1
5   4       b           1.0     1.2

I was able to create a pivot table that grouped the data as I needed it, but I'm having a hard time unstacking it while creating new column names to identify the data accordingly.
table = pd.pivot_table(df,
                       values=['value1', 'value2'],
                       index = 'IDNum',
                       columns = 'Category')
table

         value1          value2
Category a    b     c    a    b     c
IDNum                       
1        1.5  2.2   NaN  2.0  3.6   NaN
2        3.6  NaN   NaN  4.5  NaN   NaN
3        NaN  6.0   5.1  NaN  6.1   8.2
4        NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  1.2   NaN

My final table would look like:
IDNum   a_value1  b_value1  c_value1  a_value2  b_value2  c_value2
1       1.5       2.2       NaN       2.0       3.6       NaN
2       3.6       NaN       NaN       4.5       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       6.0       5.1       NaN       6.1       8.2
4       NaN       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.2       NaN


This will work:
table.columns = [f"{t[1]}_{t[0]}" for t in table.columns.to_flat_index()]
table = table.reset_index(col_level=1)

   IDNum  a_value1  b_value1  c_value1  a_value2  b_value2  c_value2
0      1       1.5       2.2       NaN       2.0       3.6       NaN
1      2       3.6       NaN       NaN       4.5       NaN       NaN
2      3       NaN       6.0       5.1       NaN       6.1       8.2
3      4       NaN       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.2       NaN


For a chained version: table.set_axis(<list>, axis=1)

Nice addition!!

Another version:
table.columns = table.swaplevel(axis=1).columns.map("_".join)
print(table.reset_index())

Prints:
   IDNum  a_value1  b_value1  c_value1  a_value2  b_value2  c_value2
0      1       1.5       2.2       NaN       2.0       3.6       NaN
1      2       3.6       NaN       NaN       4.5       NaN       NaN
2      3       NaN       6.0       5.1       NaN       6.1       8.2
3      4       NaN       1.0       NaN       NaN       1.2       NaN

